# jq: How can I pipe objects from array to different files based on data in object?

Tags: json, bash, jq, data-partitioning

I have a large array of objects stored in a master JSON file. I want to loop through that array, take each object, and append it to a new file based on a field in the object (in this case, the state name). In other words, in a set of data containing many states, I want to filter it out to a file for each state.

I'm using an existing JQ expression to filter for only the data I actually need:

```
{ fipscode: .fipscode, level: .level, polid: .polid, polnum: .polnum, precinctsreporting: .precinctsreporting, precinctsreportingpct: .precinctsreportingpct, precinctstotal: .precinctstotal, raceid: .raceid, runoff: .runoff, statepostal: .statepostal, votecount: .votecount, votepct: .votepct, winner: .winner }
```

Here's a sample of my input:

```
[
    { "ballotorder": 2, "candidateid": "9718", "delegatecount": 0, "description": null, "electiondate": "2018-08-28", "electtotal": 0, "electwon": 0, "fipscode": null, "first": "Doug", "id": "3015-polid-64364-state-AZ-1", "incumbent": true, "initialization_data": false, "is_ballot_measure": false, "last": "Ducey", "lastupdated": "2018-08-30T00:01:38.897Z", "level": "state", "national": true, "officeid": "G", "officename": "Governor", "party": "GOP", "polid": "64364", "polnum": "5554", "precinctsreporting": 1488, "precinctsreportingpct": 0.9993000000000001, "precinctstotal": 1489, "raceid": "3015", "racetype": "Primary", "racetypeid": "R", "reportingunitid": "state-AZ-1", "reportingunitname": null, "runoff": false, "seatname": null, "seatnum": null, "statename": "Arizona", "statepostal": "AZ", "test": false, "uncontested": false, "votecount": 355455, "votepct": 0.705493, "winner": true },
    { "ballotorder": 2, "candidateid": "21689", "delegatecount": 0, "description": null, "electiondate": "2018-08-28", "electtotal": 0, "electwon": 0, "fipscode": null, "first": "Ron", "id": "10046-polid-62557-state-FL-1", "incumbent": false, "initialization_data": false, "is_ballot_measure": false, "last": "DeSantis", "lastupdated": "2018-08-29T19:29:50.367Z", "level": "state", "national": true, "officeid": "G", "officename": "Governor", "party": "GOP", "polid": "62557", "polnum": "13918", "precinctsreporting": 5968, "precinctsreportingpct": 1.0, "precinctstotal": 5968, "raceid": "10046", "racetype": "Primary", "racetypeid": "R", "reportingunitid": "state-FL-1", "reportingunitname": null, "runoff": false, "seatname": null, "seatnum": null, "statename": "Florida", "statepostal": "FL", "test": false, "uncontested": false, "votecount": 913997, "votepct": 0.564728, "winner": true },
    { "ballotorder": 2, "candidateid": "45555", "delegatecount": 0, "description": null, "electiondate": "2018-08-28", "electtotal": 0, "electwon": 0, "fipscode": null, "first": "Rex", "id": "38538-polid-67011-state-OK-1", "incumbent": false, "initialization_data": false, "is_ballot_measure": false, "last": "Lawhorn", "lastupdated": "2018-08-29T02:44:44.610Z", "level": "state", "national": true, "officeid": "G", "officename": "Governor", "party": "Lib", "polid": "67011", "polnum": "40784", "precinctsreporting": 1951, "precinctsreportingpct": 1.0, "precinctstotal": 1951, "raceid": "38538", "racetype": "Runoff", "racetypeid": "L", "reportingunitid": "state-OK-1", "reportingunitname": null, "runoff": false, "seatname": null, "seatnum": null, "statename": "Oklahoma", "statepostal": "OK", "test": false, "uncontested": false, "votecount": 379, "votepct": 0.409287, "winner": false }
]
```

As output, I would expect to have a `Arizona.json` containing only the item(s) from that state, and also filtered to remove unwanted fields:

```
[
  { "fipscode": null, "level": "state", "polid": "64364", "polnum": "5554", "precinctsreporting": 1488, "precinctsreportingpct": 0.9993000000000001, "precinctstotal": 1489, "raceid": "3015", "runoff": false, "statepostal": "AZ", "votecount": 355455, "votepct": 0.705493, "winner": true }
]
```

...and likewise for the other states involved (`Florida.json` and `Oklahoma.json`).

---

Here's the bash and jq script I have so far:

```
cat master.json |
jq -cn --stream 'fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs))' |
jq -c '.statename as $state | {
    fipscode: .fipscode,
    level: .level,
    polid: .polid,
    polnum: .polnum,
    precinctsreporting: .precinctsreporting,
    precinctsreportingpct: .precinctsreportingpct,
    precinctstotal: .precinctstotal,
    raceid: .raceid,
    runoff: .runoff,
    statepostal: .statepostal,
    votecount: .votecount,
    votepct: .votepct,
    winner: .winner
}'
```

What I can't figure out is how to intercept each row so I can determine where the output should go. Is this possible?

Comment: When you say "append each row to a file", what do you mean by that? Are you wanting to edit an existing file in-place? Generate an output stream? Something else?

Comment: Making this a proper [mcve], with usable inputs (not fake data that isn't real JSON, but inputs someone can actually test a proposed answer with) and sample output data that would be generated by those inputs would be a big step towards having an answerable question.

Comment: (If you wanted, say, a separate output file per state, that's a different question, and an interesting one -- requires tools that aren't there in pure/baseline jq, but it's doable even so... but please [edit] the question so we can be completely certain as to exactly what it is you're asking for).

Comment: I want a separate output file per state, yes. I'll edit the question. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Do see the "minimal" part of MCVE guidelines -- ideally, we want a sample simplified as much as possible while still being complete enough to let answers be tested without requiring changes.

Comment: ...pruning some of the extra fields so we could have at least two entries for the same state, for example, would be a significant improvement in terms of ensuring test coverage for important behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with one copy of `jq` splitting out data items from the input file, and then another instance *per state* collating those data items together, with bash providing the glue. See the following example, for bash 4.2 or newer (might work with 4.1, I'd need to check).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[123].*|4.[01].*) echo "ERROR: Bash 4.2 required" >&2; exit 1;; esac

input_file=$1
[[ -s $input_file ]] || { echo "Usage: ${0##*/} input-file" >&2; exit 1; }

jq_split_script='
# modify this function to fit your needs
def relevantContentOnly:
  { fipscode, level, polid, polnum, precinctsreporting, precinctsreportingpct, precinctstotal, raceid, runoff, statepostal, votecount, votepct, winner };

.[] | [.statename, (relevantContentOnly | tojson)] | @tsv
'

# Use an associative array to map from state names to output FDs
declare -A out_fds=( )

# Read state / line-of-data pairs from our JQ script...
while IFS=$'\t' read -r state data; do
  # If we don't already have a writer for the current state, start one.
  if [[ ! ${out_fds[$state]} ]]; then
    exec {new_fd}> >(jq -n '[inputs]' >"$state.json")
    out_fds[$state]=$new_fd
  fi
  # Regardless, send the data to the FD we have for this state
  printf '%s\n' "$data" >&${out_fds[$state]}
done < <(jq -rc "$jq_split_script" <"$input_file") # ...running the JQ script above.

# close output FDs, so the JQ instances all flush
for fd in "${!out_fds[@]}"; do
  exec {fd}>&-
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution piggybacking on what you started with:

```
< master.json jq -cn --stream 'fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs))' |
  jq -cr '.statename, {
    fipscode,
    level,
    polid,
    polnum,
    precinctsreporting,
    precinctsreportingpct,
    precinctstotal,
    raceid,
    runoff,
    statepostal,
    votecount,
    votepct,
    winner
}' | while read -r statename && read -r object
do
  echo "$object" >> "$statename.json"
done
```

Note that this will append the objects to any existing "$statename.json" files.

With your [original] sample data, the above produces Arizona.json, Florida.json, and Oklahoma.json

### Tweak

If the overhead in using `echo` is an issue, then you could use `awk`:

```
awk '
  fn!="" {print > fn; fn=""; next}
  {fn=$0 ".json";
   if (fns[fn]!=1){fns[fn]=1; print fn > "filenames.txt"}}'
```

### Finale

Since you want these files to contain arrays of objects, you could then use `jq -s` to achieve the final results.  I'd probably collect the filenames within the `while` loop (naively, e.g. `echo "$statename.json" >> filenames.txt`), and then use `sponge`:

```
sort -u filenames.txt | 
  while read -r fn ; do 
    jq -s . "$fn" | sponge "$fn"
  done
```

Comment: I understand trying to avoid bash 4.x-isms, but re-opening the output file for every single line is pretty messy. Might use `awk` to replace the `while` loop at the end -- GNU awk, at least, will automatically maintain a cache of pre-opened FDs for different output files and reuse them appropriately rather than doing the repeated open/write/close thing as this bash code does.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Sure, I was thinking of using `awk` at the end, but thought I'd focus on the main hurdle the OP seemed to be facing, thinking that as a percentage of total CPU time, the difference would probably be fairly small.  Do you have any numbers?

Comment: I'd be wanting to look at wall-clock time, not CPU time; a lot is going to be I/O wait and syscall overhead, depending on filesystem details. Let's see -- the US has ~500,000 elected offices if we count state and local. Using best-of-3 timing, I get 0m59.324s wall-clock for `time for ((i=0; i<500000; i++)); do echo >>test; done`, and 9.885s for `time for ((i=0; i<500000; i++)); do echo test; done >>test`.